# Add small icon in Notification Icon

Tags: java, android, notifications, notification-icons

I m using below code to get Notificaiton Icon. This give normal notification icon but there is small white box at the bottom right corner of it. How can I set icon for that too.

```
 public void not() {
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.lnc)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.lnc))
                .setContentTitle("My Title")
                .setContentText("Done").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.lnc)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lollipop onwards, your small icon must be monochrome** i.e. transparent background & white color, otherwise it'll be displayed as a white box. So convert your R.mipmap.lnc into a silhouette i.e. create your icon in such a way that the parts you want to show should be white & the background be transparent. If you want to add a color to the background you can do it using setColor method.

Read [this](https://clevertap.com/blog/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/) link.

Comment: So there I one main icon, then it has a circle in right bottom corner and a small white box in that. Setcolor set the color of circle from default Gray to color chosen though white box remain white.

Comment: There won't be any white box then, there will be a circle with the background color set & inside that will be your white icon that you created.

Comment: yes, actually I was using mipmap icon instead of drawable. Now I can see my small icon.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.YOUR_SMALL_ICON`) to set small icon for Notification.

**FYI,** According to the design guidelines you must use a `silhouette` for `Builder.setSmallIcon()`. See [design gideline](https://material.io/guidelines/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons)

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationSmallIcon())
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.lnc))
            .setContentTitle("My Title")
            .setContentText("Done")
            .build();

..................
..........................

private int getNotificationSmallIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.ic_silhouette : R.drawable.ic_launcher;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;

 mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Captian Mansoura")
                .setContentText("Busy , On trip Now")
             .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.lnc))

                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notify_offline);
```

try this